# Error 5: Access denied when I try to update VScode software

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open VScode, the following error appears:

"The installer was unable to create the C: \ Users \ André directory
Error 5: Access is denied "
The same happens when I try to do a software update of VScode in the Help -> Check for Upgrades tab.
I had problems with the VScode configuration previously because I had "André" as a directory. So I chose to switch to "Andre". I emphasize that in this process I also changed the name in the records.

I tried to perform a new installation on top of this one already installed but the same error also occurs.
Will I have a corrupted file or do I just have to change directories?

I wanna solve it. I don't know how i can proceed.